# (Functional Analysis) A Remark About Parseval's Identity

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely Hilbert spaces. In the text, the author gives the following theorem:

> **Theorem A** (*Parseval's identity*): Let $\{e_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ be an orthonormal system. Then $\{e_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ is a basis in $H$ if and only if for all $x\in H$
> $$
> ||x||^2=\sum_{i\geq 1}|\langle x,e_i \rangle|^2.\tag{1}
> $$

If it's not obvious, $H$ is a Hilbert space. Now, I understand the proof of **Theorem A**; however, the author follows up with the following remark which I don't understand completely:

> **Remark 1**: If $(1)$ is true for a dense subset of $x$'s, it implies that $\{e_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ is a complete system which by **Theorem B** implies that $\{e_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ is a basis.

I'm not going to fully write out **Theorem B**, but it's just the fact that a complete orthonormal system in a Hilbert space is a basis for it. What I don't understand about **Remark 1** is the "if $(1)$ is true for a dense subset of $x$'s, it implies that $\{e_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ is a complete system". Any help here will be appreciated.

---

I'll add here that $\{e_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ being a *complete* system in a normed space $X$ means the linear span
$$
\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i e_i:\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{N},\text{ for all scalars }\alpha_i\right\}
$$
of the vectors $\{e_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ is a dense set in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x$ in the dense set check that $\|x-\sum \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i\|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}-\sum |\langle x, e_i \rangle|^{2}=0$. This shows that $x-\sum \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i $ belongs to the closed subspace spanned by $e_i$'s. This automatically implies that any vector in the closure of the  dense set is also in the closed subspace spanned by $e_i$'s.